# How to structure golang api that uses function from python file

Tags: python, api, go, ctypes

I am writing an api that will be sending messages over websockets.

I have a python monitoring function that is used to monitor and format the data which will be sent over the websocket. If this monitoring function was written in golang, I'd run the function on a separate goroutine and each time new data was fetched by the function I would send it through a channel and then send it over the websocket connection.

How/is it possible to achieve a similar type of behaviour if the monitoring function is a python function? I'd rather not use grpc as speed is important for my use case

Comment: use thread, one thread to fetch data, log it/monitor it and then it pass data to main thread and main thread send it to websocket., with asyncio you can use coroutine and achive same

Comment: Can you be specific on: do you want call your existing Python monitor program from Go? Or, do you want to implement a pure Go monitor program that will communicate via websocket (and discard the Python program)?

Comment: @EvandroPomatti I want to call my existing python monitor program from golang, the idea would that it would run continuously whilst passing any messages back to golang so that they can be sent over the websocket

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a Python function to monitor and format data in a Go program, you can use any of the implementation of the CPython API (e.g., [cpy3](https://github.com/go-python/cpy3)) to call Python functions from a Go program. [gpython](https://github.com/go-python/gpython), e.g., uses the CPython API to embed Python in Go. Here's na example of how you can use one such API for monitoring functions of Python.

```golang
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/include/python3.8
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lpython3.8
// #include <Python.h>
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    C.Py_Initialize()
    defer C.Py_Finalize()

    pyName := C.CString("monitor_module")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(pyName))
    pyModule := C.PyImport_ImportModule(pyName)
    if pyModule == nil {  // handle error  }

    pyFunc := C.PyObject_GetAttrString(pyModule, C.CString("monitor_function"))
    pyArgs := C.PyTuple_New(0)
    pyResult := C.PyObject_CallObject(pyFunc, pyArgs)

    result := C.GoString(C.PyUnicode_AsUTF8(pyResult)) // Python result to a Go string
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```